# Can Game Center integrate with non-game iOS application

Tags: ios, game-center

I am working on an education application but I want to implement a leader board and achievement feature to it. So I come up with Game Center.

My question is, this application is now in the education category and I don't want to move it to Game category. Will it be rejected in the application review because I integrate Game Center with a non-game application?

Comment: Good question. Have you looked at the [app review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html)? I guess it won't be in there, but maybe worth a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is not a "Game" then it will not be allowed on the App Store if it integrates Game Center.

See here... http://abitofcode.com/2012/05/so-what-happened-to-sketchshare/

This app was removed from the app store (having previously been a front page feature) because it was using Game Center and was not a game.

Comment: This is a pity considering the content of [this Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=GameKit) where it explicitly says any application can use GameKit.

>Add networking capabilities to applications with the Game Kit framework. Although you can use this framework in any type of application, it is commonly used to implement the kind of peer-to-peer connectivity and in-game voice features found in multiplayer games.

Comment: This isn't true =/ For example look to this app: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/24/100-cameras-in-1-latest-non-game-app-to-use-game-center-on-ios/ also, there is no such rule that Game Center is for games only. Also it depends on app. I think educational app can be with Game Center.

Comment: I'm only going by what actually happened. Like I said. The app I linked was app of the week before being removed. What apples logic was is not known.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple,](https://developer.apple.com/game-center/)

> **Tips and Best Practices**
>
> Game Center should only be used in games and entertainment apps, as it is intended to complement gaming functionality within an
>   app.

Answer (score 0):

I copy the game center related rules down here. But I do not see any description about my issue. Does that mean I can integrate it with my app?

6.Game Center

6.1
Apps that display any Player ID to end users or any third party will be rejected

6.2
Apps that use Player IDs for any use other than as approved by the Game Center terms will be rejected

6.3
Developers that attempt to reverse lookup, trace, relate, associate, mine, harvest, or otherwise exploit Player IDs, alias, or other information obtained through the Game Center will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

6.4
Game Center information, such as Leaderboard scores, may only be used in Apps approved for use with the Game Center

6.5
Apps that use Game Center service to send unsolicited messages, or for the purpose of phishing or spamming will be rejected

6.6
Apps that excessively use the network capacity or bandwidth of the Game Center will be rejected

6.7
Apps that transmit viruses, files, computer code, or programs that may harm or disrupt the normal operation of the Game Center service will be rejected