# Can iOS GameCenter be used for an app that's technically not a game?

Tags: ios, gamekit

I am working on a feature in an app which syncs data between 2 remote users. Semantically, it is not exactly a "game" though, in my case it is about musical jamming, let's say it's similar to the local network jam feature in Garageband, but over the internet.

Would it be allowed to use GameCenter for this? Would I need to wrap this feature into a "game within the non-game app"? Would that mean that the app would need to be in the games category of the App Store?

Are there examples of any apps which successfully do this?

It would be nice to be able to use this API for data synchronisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the approval guidelines that prohibits the use of game center in regular apps.

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#game-center

Never the less, several apps has been rejected or kicked out from AppStore because of usage of Game Center in 'not-a-game'-apps. See this blog post about what happened to [SketchShare](http://abitofcode.com/2012/05/so-what-happened-to-sketchshare/).

Comment: The guidelines are very vague and this answer says different. GameKit may be ok to use, GameCenter not so much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209626/can-game-center-integrate-with-none-game-ios-application

Answer (score 0):

You can use it. It is only way of using Bluetooth for old devices. If you are targeting newer ios devices you can use bluetooth framework